# Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: baseUrl must end in /: url

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, base-url

I am using Retrofit2 for API parsing.

I'm using `retrofit:2.2.0` and I'm using `converter-gson:2.2.0'`, in the get method, there is an error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: baseUrl must end in /

I have checked my code and there is no problem.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    initViews();
    **loadJSON();**

private void loadJSON(){
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            **.baseUrl(BASE_URL)**
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
```

Comment: add "/" in last of base url

Comment: base url be something like `www.google.com/`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add "/" in your BASE URL. eg `somesite.com/` or `facebook.com/profile/`